# How to execute sass watch command on more than one folder

Tags: css, sass

I have following directory structure

```
src/
    sass/
        base.scss
        global.scss
    components/
        Menu/
            sass/
                styles.scss
        Contents/
            sass/
                style.scss
```

As you can see I have `global` styles and styles for each component. What I am doing now is when I edit `global` styles then I run `sass --watch sass:css` on global styles folder. When I edit any component styles then I run `sass --watch sass:css` command on that component's sass folder.

What I need is to run `sass --watch` command so that it compiles all the scss files that I am editing. **How can I make this work?**

Answer (score 0):

first I highly recommend using Compass to compile your scss files. 
to use it follow steps in this link:
[Install Compass-style](http://compass-style.org/install/)

after installing it create a project file in your src folder
***config.rb***
after that go the src folder then run:

```
compass watch
```

**it will compile all scss files**

you can specify a lot of setting
the content of config.rb should look something like this

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "../wwwroot/css"
sass_dir = "./"
images_dir = "/wwwroot/images"
cache_path = "c:/tempscss"
```

you can check this link to know more about what you can configure
[Compass Configuration](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you consider using build tools such as Gulp or Grunt? It would make things tad easier for you. You can target multiple folders using wildcards such as `'./src/sass/**/*.scss'` or `['./src/components/scss/*.scss', './src/modules/**/*.scss']`

Setup in gulp is just

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
});

gulp.task('watch',function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

With npm only, it would probably look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch:sass": "onchange 'src/scss/**/*.scss' -- npm run sass:css",
}
```

find more info here https://github.com/Qard/onchange